# I need to read a text file in python and get selected values into a separate array

Tags: python

I have a text file containing data as follows

```
Generated by trjconv : a bunch of waters t=   0.00000
3000   
1SOL     OW    1   1.5040   2.7580   0.6820
1SOL    HW1    2   1.4788   2.7853   0.7702
1SOL    HW2    3   1.4640   2.8230   0.6243
2SOL     OW    4   1.5210   0.9510   2.2050
2SOL    HW1    5   1.5960   0.9780   2.1520
2SOL    HW2    6   1.4460   0.9940   2.1640
3SOL     OW    7   2.1520   2.9020   2.5480
3SOL    HW1    8   2.1351   2.9646   2.6185
```

up to 3000 raw.

From this I need to grab selected values into a separate list, like follows:

```
  X=[1.5040, 1.5210, 2.1520,    etc]
  Y=[2.7580, 0.9510, 2.9020,    etc]
  Z=[0.6820, 2.2050, 2.5480,    etc]
```

Can any one help me to write this code?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the csv module? Have you looked at the Pandas library?

Comment: I can read it using read command but i want to grab those specific data into another file. I am new one to python.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Actually I need some hints to try this. which kind of cords might help to do this

Comment: @MartijnPieters how hard will it be to write a spider that check user balance == 1 and question tagged 'python' and no python code leading to post that comment? better than copy and paste from your notes there :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters or is it a spider already?

Comment: @Guy: It is a [browser extension](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se). The rest is of the spider consists of me opening new questions.

Comment: @user3187811: Did you do any research of your own yet? What did you find? Can you share your research in your post? We can help you find the missing puzzle pieces, but only if you share with us what pieces you already have.

Comment: i can read that file in python using as follows,     file = open('gro.txt','r')  for line in file:  print(file.readline())

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194830/need-help-to-read-gromac-file-in-python

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194830/need-help-to-read-gromac-file-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good way I guess.

```
F = open('Data.gro', 'r')
A = open('XYZ.txt', 'w')
XO = []
YO = []
ZO = []
XHW1 = []
YHW1 = []
ZHW1 = []
XHW2 = []
YHW2 = []
ZHW2 = []
I = range(1, 10)
with open('Data.gro') as F:
    for line in F:
        if line.split()[0] == '3000':
            print('Frame')
            A.write('%s\n' % 'Frame')
            for R in I:
                line = next(F)
                P = line.split()
                if P[1] == 'OW':
                    x = float(P[3])
                    y = float(P[4])
                    z = float(P[5])
                    XO.append(x)
                    YO.append(y)
                    ZO.append(z)
                 else:
                    if P[1] == 'HW1':
                        x = float(P[3])
```

same pattern can use to extract data.

Comment: This is a terrible way! Instead of a torrent of ad hoc variables, use a dictionary to collect groups of values by label.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that your data is saved in `my_data.csv`, and the first OW row is the first row, this should do the trick.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('my_data.csv', usecols=[3, 4, 5])[::3]
x, y, z = data.transpose()
```

If you have headers like in your example, and want to start on the second line, just change `[::3]` to `[1::3]`.

Comment: No this is different in between I have some lines with word. After every 3000 rows there are additional 3 rows have words. Actually I have written a program to read it follow this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194830/need-help-to-read-gromac-file-in-python] Appriciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Using line split function you can search specific point then you can read next records after you have found that. Like shanaka motioned.

```
line.split()[0]=='3000'
```